# How can I close the "edit" option from a question when it has been answered? bbPress Plugin || Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, bbpress

I was wondering if there is an option in the bbPress plugin where, whenever a Topic has a reply, the option to edit the question right before the answer will be disabled.

*For a better example*:

---

**Let's suppose that a new user starts a topic**:

[image]

---

**This button here is the "EDIT" button but simply in the Greek language:**

[image]

---

**Now Let's say that somebody answered to this topic:**

[image]

As you can see the "EDIT" button for the question the logged in user made, is still visible and usable.

---

**QUESTION**:

- How can I disable the "EDIT" button after a answer has been given to the topic?

*Thank you in advance for your time and effort!*